# How to pass parameters to template event in meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

How to pass values to template events

Html

```
<template name="Header">
 <div class="testClass">Text1</div> // pass a = 1
 <div class="testClass">Text2</div> // pass a = 2
</template>
```

Javascript

```
Template.Header.events({
'click .testClass':function(event, template){
    console.log(a) //print a values
  }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the appropriate data context, using child templates for example :

HTML

```
<template name="Header">
  {{> test text="Text1" a=1}}
  {{> test text="Text2" a=2}}
</template>

<template name="test">
  <div class="test">{{text}}</div>
</template>
```

JS

```
Template.test.events({
  "click .test": function(event, template){
    console.log(this.a);
  }
});
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. However, 'template.data.a' did.

Comment: Are you sure you have the exact same code, because `this.a` definitely returns `1` for me.